# How to access all objects in one class from a different swift file

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

I'm trying to change the properties of a few IBOutlets from a different swift file and class. Ex: run function in class B (type UIView) to alter the alpha of IBOutlet in class A (type UIViewController). I've tried many different ways of accessing them (extensions,superclasses)  but I still get nil values for these outlets. I am aware that this is because the view is allocated for but not loaded, but I cannot find a way to store and access class "A"'s outlets correctly to avoid this. Here is my code from class "B" :

```
 let mainView = MainViewController()  //Code in B
  var changeAlpha = mainView.changeText() //Code in B

func changeAlpha() {               //Code in class MainViewController
    self.hotLabel.alpha = 0
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All the `iboutlet`s will be nil, until the `UIViewController` has been presented somewhere. The `iBoutlet` populate when `viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: You should save a value, something like `hotLabelAlpha`, in your `MainViewController` and set it before presenting like `mainView.hotLabelAlpha = 0` and when `viewDidLoad` of your ViewController is called you should call `self.hotLabel.alpha = hotLabelAlpha`.

Comment: Ok thanks that works too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to allocate the `MainViewController` again.

Try to access the existing `MainViewController` instead.

```
var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.nextResponder()
            if let mainView = parentResponder as? MainViewController {
                var changeAlpha = mainView.changeText()
            }
        }
```

When you try to  create an object of `MainViewController` class (which is already includes your data), the values that you have stored earlier will not be accessible because the reference will be different for these two class objects

You have to pass the existing `MainViewController` class into the B class or try to access the existing `MainViewController` or implement the messaging concepts.

The only way to solve these kind of issues is, try to study the OOPS basic concepts (especially object life cycle, allocation etc..) before writing the code.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I have added more details for you.